# Dual Booting pre-installed Win7 64bit w/ Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot

I bought a Asus Eee PC 1215B MU17 netbook with the AMD C-50 fusion chip.  It's pre-installed with Win7 64bit, and has 4 partitions:

- 100 GB Primary C:
- 16 GB hidden which looks like the Win7 install files
- 117 GB D: Data
- 100 MB I think this may contain the files for their quick on Express Gate OS

I've done numerous dual boots of WinXP and Ubuntu on machines I've built from scratch, but I've never had to deal with this kind of pre-installed setup, Win7 or the issue of not having any install media.

I figure I'll need the latest version of Ubuntu to get support for the graphics on the C-50 chip.

Any advice on how to proceed?  Any gotcha's to watch out for?  Is installing onto one of the existing NTFS partitions still an option?

Comment: Are they all primary partitions? If they are you will need to remove (at least) one of them

Comment: The one to remove would be D:, obviously resize C: if you want more than 100 GB within Windows... You can only have 4 maximum primary partitions on a hard drive, for any more you need to create an Extended partition (which requires losing 1 primary). You can only have 1 Extended partition, but within the Extended partition you can any number of Logical partitions (which cannot contain an OS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing it into an image file onto the existing NTFS partition might be the easiest option here. You can use WUBI, the [Windows installer for Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer) here. The process is pretty easy and straight forward. There is also a [more detailed guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) in the Ubuntu wiki.

Comment: Any noticeable performance hit for the translation between NTFS and ext3/4 ?